# Hide of a hidden element...How bad?

Tags: jquery, hide

How bad is to do a hide of a hidden element?

So, let's say the element `#myelement` is hidden, and I do a `$('#element').hide()`. Is that bad? Should I check if it's visible first?

Thanks!

Comment: It's bad like showing a block element! :) if you're talking about one only element.... don't bother. Clients are waiting.

Comment: Why to hide a hidden element ? What's the purpose of that ?

Comment: @Vucko: Not on purpose. Just to avoid complicating the code (with the logic necessary to avoid redundant hiding).

Comment: You don't need to check it it's visible, before hiding it.

Comment: Vucko, I am not trying to hide a hidden element. Is a "just in case" question :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

jQuery checks if the element is visible and hides only if it's visible: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L78

```
    } else if ( !values[ index ] && !isHidden( elem ) ) {
        jQuery._data( elem, "olddisplay", curCSS( elem, "display" ) );
    }
```

So you don't need to perform additional checks. Any manual check would make the performance (and readability actually) worse.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a choice between

```
$("my-element").hide();
```

and

```
if(!$("my-element").is(":visible")) {
    $("my-element").hide();
})
```

it is much simpler (better?) to just have the first line for readability sake. jQuery will do the check whether you do it or not.

Comment: Looks like @zerkms already said the same thing. **Should** really click on  that Load New answers link, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you hide an element that is already hidden, nothing will happen.

The only way that it is 'bad' is that it is executing code which doesn't need to be executed.

You could check if it is hidden using is():

```
if(!$("my-element").is(":visible")) {
    $("my-element").hide();
})
```

Comment: However that results in other code being executed that did not need to be (the check code).

Comment: true, but this check code may be less than jQuery's internal checking code...? Would have to profile them both to be sure :)

Comment: in the presumably more frequent case (that the element actually needs hiding), *both* checks would be run.

Comment: True again, be interesting to see if it saved any cycles when the element doesn't need hiding

Answer (score 0):

For only `hiding` the element you don't need to check whether the element is already `hidden` or not but if you have a case like if the element is then show else do something else then you can use

```
if ($('your-element').is(':hidden')) {
$('your-element').show();
} else {
//do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to check the visibility of the element before hiding it.

```
 $('#element').hide();
```

it will causes some issues in Internet Explorer(IE9). Some time page will not load properly. Some content will be missed from the page.

The following code is much better.

```
if(!$("#myelement").is(":visible")) {
    $("#myelement").hide();
})
```